# How delete every 3rd Element of a vector?

Tags: r

I have following vector:

```
myList = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
```

How can I remove EVERY 3rd element?
(not like this:
`myList=myList[-3]`,
`myList=myList[-6]`,)

I need the following output:

```
1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `myList[((1:length(myList)) %%3)!=0]`

Comment: @Dave2e how do I permanently remove every 3rd element from the vector :/?

Comment: Assign it back to `myList`: `myList <- myList[((1:length(myList)) %%3)!=0]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a sequence as the index

```
myList[-c(3*1:5)]

[1]  1  2  4  5  7  8 10 11 13 14
```

You can use sequencing functions to make it consistent with any vector lengths with this:

```
myList[seq_along(myList)%%3!=0]
```

and this (credit to @thelatemail for that):

```
myList[-seq(3, length(myList), 3)]
```

Comment: The sequence could also be made to work with any length - `myList[-seq(3, length(myList), 3)]`

Answer (score 6):

You may also use a recycling logical vector:

```
myList[c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)]
```

-output:

```
[1]  1  2  4  5  7  8 10 11 13 14
```

Answer (score 3):

We could first extract each third element and then remove:

```
myList1 <- myList[seq(0, length(myList), 3)]
myList[-myList1]
```

```
 [1]  1  2  4  5  7  8 10 11 13 14
```