# How would I change every other element in a vector to the same value?

Tags: r, vector

If I have a vector such as:

```
vector <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

how would I change it for every other element to be one number? For example:

```
vector <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

Would a for loop work best? I'm not sure how to make it every 2 elements.

Thanks!

Comment: A very similar question with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69125184/how-delete-every-3rd-element-of-a-vector/69125228#69125228

Comment: [Another candidate ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461829)

Answer (score 2):

We can modify inplace with a recycling logical index:

```
vector <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
vector[c(FALSE, TRUE)]<-2
```

Or use the `modulo` operator with `replace`

```
replace(vector, seq_along(vector)%%2==0, 2)

 [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessary to perform with a loop. We can use square brackets (`[]`) to index the `vector`, when the position of the element can be divided by 2 (`%% 2 == 0`), change the element to 2.

```
vector[seq_along(vector) %% 2 == 0] <- 2

[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```